# How to place iOS Share Facebook and Instagram Share buttons in one place?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, share, instagram

I have a app which **Share Images** . I have tried Social Framework and UIActivity is working fine . But what i want is to Put **Facebook and Instagram** in one place,i couldn't find a way to do it. I have searched alot, is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

To change type of file:

```
- (void)share {
    NSString *path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/tmptmpimg.jpg"];
    [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_img, 1.0) writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

    _documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
    _documentInteractionController.delegate = self;
    [_documentInteractionController presentOptionsMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES];
}

- (void)documentInteractionController:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller willBeginSendingToApplication:(NSString *)application {
    if ([self isWhatsApplication:application]) {
        NSString *savePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/tmptmpimg.wai"];
        [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_img, 1.0) writeToFile:savePath atomically:YES];
        controller.URL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:savePath];
        controller.UTI = @"net.whatsapp.image";
    }
}

- (BOOL)isWhatsApplication:(NSString *)application {
    if ([application rangeOfString:@"whats"].location == NSNotFound) { // unfortunately, no other way...
         return NO;
    } else {
         return YES;
    }
}
```

This way we can use all options- Facebook, Twitter,instagram and WhatsApp.

The problem with showing only selected options is still not solved, but it's the minor one.

Comment: is possible to put Facebook share into UIDocumentInteractionController? so it shows in the same place

Comment: what is the UTI for Facebook?  can you put a code for Instagram and Facebook?

Comment: can you try my code or not?

Comment: if working then accept as answer

Comment: if any problem..[continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93135/discussion-between-maulik-and-nanweera).

Comment: i have a issue ,i just used your code and put a image and tried all working but Facebook shows an EMPTY image box in sharing area after you press Facebook button

Comment: plz Nslog...image url...in log..link exist or not...

Comment: all are working fine only Facebook shows empty image, do i have to implement Facebook seperatly?

Comment: same code working in my app...you missed somthing..

Comment: i get log after i press Facebook "get this Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior "

Comment: can you possible to provide me your project? that would be huge relief